# I can't import yfinance and pandas in JupyterNotebook or pycharm. (Mac M1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm working on M1.
I tried to import pandas in Jupyter.
But it doesn't work.

When I check it using 'pip show pandas' in Jupyter, it appears like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpaRE.png)

But I can't import Pandas in Jupyter.
Error appears.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhW6V.jpg)

The image is too big, so error message is cropped.
Here is the last sentence of the error message.

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so,
> 0x0002): tried:
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64e'))

When I checked the place where python3 is installed, it appears like this.

~> which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Jupyter's Version : 3.4.3

pip's Version : 22.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

What do you think is problem?

Comment: I suggest you try [brew based Python installation](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python) because it makes it easier to install native library dependencies needed to install Python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have some similar issues with importing after I pip installed the needed modules piecemeal.  To fix this, I started from scratch and used Anaconda on both mac and windows machines to install python and the needed modules without any further issues.

https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution#Downloads

I also have been using more virtual environments, which I would recommend looking up afterwards.